# After erasing input field, javascript won't read it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple function for fetching a result,

```
<script language="javascript">
        function searching(value){
            url="ajax_search.php?st=usu&sear="+value;
            ajax(url);
        }
        searching(" ");
</script>
```

And my html:

```
<input type="text" id="usu" value="" name="usu" style="width:250px;" onKeyUP="searching(this.value)" />
```

My problem is that, if you write, for example= "test" on the input field, it will search and show all the matches for "test", if you erase that and search for "example" it wouldn't do anything. Like if you haven't typed anything.

Can someone help me?

EDIT: The console says:

```
http://pesquisa.mqb.com.br/relatorios/pesq/ajax_search.php?st=usu&search=TEST Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Found the problem, my firewall was blocking due to many connections try in a short space time as I press backspace much faster than I type. Thank you for commenting!

Comment: is there some info in the console?

Comment: are there any records that are matched as "example" ?

Comment: If the function getting called? `console.log()` is your friend.

Comment: http://pesquisa.mqb.com.br/relatorios/pesq/ajax_search.php?st=usu&sear=TEST Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Put that error in your question, hit the edit button and add it in.

Comment: @Hardik yes, there is

Comment: I think your site is down.. ask your hosting provider.. Because your site is not running.

Comment: It's internal use only, @Hardik

Comment: @IuryPiva don't edit the subject with the `CLOSED` word, simply add your own answer and then accept it. It's the correct behaviour in this community. And welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna modify onKeyUp to onkeyup

```
<input type="text" id="usu" value="" name="usu" style="width:250px;" onkeyup="searching(this.value)" />
```

Also, print the value you get in the log:

```
function searching(value){
    url = "ajax_search.php?st=usu&sear="+value;
    ajax(url);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Okay, it showed something like= "T" working. "TE" working. "TES" working. "TEST" working. "TES" working. "TE" working. "T" working.  and then when i erase it all i get "script.js:8 GET http://pesquisa.mqb.com.br/relatorios/pesq/ajax_busca.php?st=usu&pesq=T 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: And the same error goes on until i reload the page.